# C# parse html with xpath

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse out stock exchange information whit a simple piece of C# from a HTML document.  The problem is that I can not get my head around the syntax, the *tr class="LomakeTaustaVari"* gets parsed out but how do I get the second bit that has no tr-class?

Here's a piece of the HTML, it repeats it self whit different values.

```
<tr class="LomakeTaustaVari">
    <td><div class="Ensimmainen">12:09</div></td>
    <td><div>MSI</div></td>
    <td><div>POH</div></td>
    <td><div>42</div></td>
    <td><div>64,50</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div class="Ensimmainen">12:09</div></td>
    <td><div>SRE</div></td>
    <td><div>POH</div></td>
    <td><div>156</div></td>
    <td><div>64,50</div></td>
</tr>
```

My C# code:

```
{
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load ("https://www.op.fi/op/henkiloasiakkaat/saastot-ja-sijoitukset/kurssit-ja-markkinat/markkinat?sivu=alltrades.html&sym=KNEBV.HSE&from=10:00&to=19:00&id=32453");

    foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='LomakeTaustaVari']")) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.InnerText);     
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Would a `//tr[not(@class)]` work to select that `<tr>` without class?

Answer (score 5):

Try to use the next xpath `//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[@class='LomakeTaustaVari']]`:

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[@class='LomakeTaustaVari']]");
```

It should select nodes that have preceding node `tr` with class `LomakeTaustaVari`.

Just FYI: if no nodes found, `SelectNodes` method returns `null`.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick...  ..Allmost, it skipped the the first row but gave me all the entries when I changed the LomakeTaustaVari to the parent class TaulukkoOtsikkorivi (outside the html code i gave you).  This definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

If you manage to get a reference to the `<tr class="LomakeTaustaVari">` element, I see two possible solutions.

You can navigate to the parent and then find all its `<tr>` children:

```
lomakeTaustaVariElement.Parent.SelectNodes("tr"); // iterate over these if needed
```

You can also use `NextSibling` to get the next `<tr>`:

```
var trWithoutClass = lomakeTaustaVariElement.NextSibling;
```

Please note that using the second alternative you may run into issues, because whitespace present in the HTML may be interpreted as being a distinct element.

To overcome this, you may recursively call `NextSibling` until you encounter a `tr` element.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I don't understand something, but the simplest XPath for any *tr* element selection should do the work:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")
```

Otherwise, in case you would like to select elements with specific *class* attributes only, it could be:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class = 'someClass1' or @class = 'someClass2']")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will iterate over all  nodes in document. You will probably also need to be more specific with starting node, so you will only select  that you are interested in.

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr")) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(row.InnerText);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like to load the page and want to use a ready `html` string, e.g. from a `WebBrowser` element, you can use the following example:

```
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
web.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.Document.Body.Parent.OuterHtml);
var q = web.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]") //XPath /html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]
```