# how do i write a Regular expression in c# for an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, c#, office365

Actually i was trying to get a response from the following URL which is office 365 calender events

```html
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events?startDateTime=2015-12-16T01:00:00&endDateTime=2015-12-17T23:00:00&$select=Subject";
```

the response from the page is something like below

```
    "Body":{"ContentType":"HTML",
"Content":"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<style type=\"text/css\" style=\"\">\r\n<!--\r\np\r\n\t{margin-top:0;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:0}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=\"ltr\">\r\n<div id=\"divtagdefaultwrapper\" style=\"font-size:12pt; color:#000000; background-color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif\">\r\n<p><br>\r\n</p>\r\n<br>\r\n<font face=\"Calibri\" size=\"1\" color=\"#404040\"><span style=\"\">.........................................................................................................................................</span></font><br>\r\n<font size=\"4\"><span style=\"font-size:16pt\"><a href=\"https://meet.lync.com/xtreamit/admin/PMYUQ2WG\" target=\"_blank\">Join online meeting</a></span></font><br>\r\n<br>\r\n<span style=\"font-size:10pt\"><a href=\"\" target=\"_blank\">Find a local number</a></span><br>\r\n<br>\r\n<font face=\"Calibri\" size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt\">Conference ID: </span>\r\n</font><br>\r\n<br>\r\n<a href=\"\" target=\"_blank\">Forgot your dial-in PIN?</a> <br>\r\n<font face=\"Calibri\" size=\"1\" color=\"#404040\"><span style=\"font-size:8pt\">.........................................................................................................................................</span></font><br>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"},
```

i just wanted to get only specific data from the above response
like

```
<a href=\"https://meet.lync.com/sds/admin/ssd\" target=\"_blank\">Join online meeting</a>
```

i tried to use Regex in the c# but it is not giving any response can any one help me in getting the right response from that office 365 calender

```
Regex expression = new Regex("<a.*?(?<attribute>href|name)=\"(?<value>.*?)\".*?>Join online meeting</a>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex expression = new Regex(@"<a [^>]*?>(?<text>.*?)</a>",  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex expression = new Regex(@"<a .*>Join online meeting</a>", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: I hope that is fake patient data. You should make an attempt to format it for us so that it is easier to read.

Comment: no that is not fake data but it is taken from original response, it is part of the original response returned by office 365

Comment: Instead of using regular expression, `JSON` is probably better suited for parsing the response...

Comment: @chinna2580 I'm not a lawyer, but I get the impression that the Information Technology Act, 2000 has something about "imposing penalty for breach of confidentiality and privacy": [Breach of privacy and Confidentiality under information Technology Act, 2000](http://www.legalserviceindia.com/article/l288-Breach-of-privacy-&-Confidentiality-.html).

Answer (score 0):

The robust solution could be as follow (regex):

```
new Regex("<a .*?>Join online meeting</a>")
```

The capturing groups could be added to the regex if necessary.

But if it is something, which should be used more than once, I'd strongly recommend to **avoid use regular expression for parsing html**. Especially for case when html text is encoded (like it is json-encoded in your case). See a lot of explanations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

The much better solution would be:

1. Use [JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/deserialize-json-with-c-sharp) to read response.
2. Use [XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405264/c-sharp-parse-html-with-xpath) to extract the necessary data from the html.