# Regex match URL if not in html comment line

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match "https://www.mysite/embed/M7znk1c-ay0"  only if it is not html comment.

So dont't match this line

```
<!--<p><iframe src="https://www.mysite/embed/M7znk1c-ay0" width="854" height="480" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>-->
```

but match this line

```
<article class="art-post"><div class="art-postcontent clearfix"><div class="art-article"><p><iframe  src="https://www.mysite/embed/M7znk1c-ay0" ></iframe></p>
```

I tried this pattern `^(?=<!--).*www.mysite\/embed\/+[\w\-]*`

but it isn't quite working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# parse html with xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405264/c-sharp-parse-html-with-xpath). There is no need for regex in your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it correctly. The correct regex is `^(?!<!--).*"(.*www.mysite\/embed\/+[\w\-]*)`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not regular so using regular expressions to parse html might not be a good idea...
@csabinho's answer `^(?!<!--).*"(.*www.mysite\/embed\/+[\w\-]*)` won't work if the URL you want to match is in middle of a page, it simply checks if line doesn't begin with a comment.

Best practice would be to create DOM and use XPath to query XML-like contents.

## Edit:

By the way you can use following code first to remove comments.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
string pattern = @"(<!--(.+?)-->)";
var res = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

and then use a simple pattern to extract the URL from result